# Can a computer with 2 GB RAM run Ubuntu with Wayland?

Tags: asus, wayland, 21.04

Should I use Wayland on 2GB RAM? It is a Asus Eeebook x2 05ta, 2GB RAM, 32 GB storage, and a 64 GB Samsung micro SD card.

Comment: That is for you to decide ;-) You can and it will be slow. But it might be acceptable for you.

Answer (score 7):

While it has just enough power to run GNOME or KDE in Wayland, this computer does not have enough resources to run the GNOME desktop with many applications. KDE consumes less memory, but it consumes relatively higher CPU cycles if you turn on fancy effects, and the Intel Atom processor of this computer may not be able to run it smoothly.

I suggest you to use Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead (or Kubuntu, without any fancy effects. Nowadays Kubuntu uses less RAM than Xubuntu). They need relatively less resource to run.

In case even [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) seem to be slow, you can use other distros tailored for older computers with less computing power. Some examples are [LXLE](https://lxle.net/), [Puppy Linux](https://puppylinux.com/), [anTiX](https://antixlinux.com/) or [Bodhi](https://www.bodhilinux.com). (Note that they are not supported on this website. But being Debian based, the user experience would be very similar to Ubuntu).

Comment: Fully agree. RAM is the main limitation here: 2 GB can run the desktop environment, but you will fill the RAM with just a few applications. Better opt for a lighter DE, or add at least 2 GB ram.

Comment: I'd say KDE is probably lighter these days than XFCE, *especially* if you turn off fancy effects, feel free to go with KUbuntu instead of XUbuntu. It runs really well on my own notebook with only 2GB of RAM. Another suggestion: install `zram-tools` to allow compressed RAM (default settings work fairly well).

Comment: @valisstillwithMonica Yeah, that is true. But KDE is so beautiful that I cannot resist turning on fancy effects (wobbly windows, magic lamp, blur, translucent KVantum themes) and it always ends up consuming more resources (usually more CPU cycles, not RAM) than my minimal XFCE setup  :-)