# Will my laptop support Ubuntu with 2 GB RAM?

Tags: configuration

My current laptop configuration is as below:
Memory - 1.9Gib
Processor - Intel Pentium(R) cpu A1018@2.10Ghz x 2
Graphics -:Intel Ivy bridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
Disk - 245 GB

When I increase my ram memory to additional 2GB a sum of 4GB ram does it sufficient to run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS latest OS?

Comment: The RAM is the bottleneck. According to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements), the recommended RAM is at least 4 GB for the standard Ubuntu desktop. Check out my other answer for alternatives when you have 2 GB RAM. https://askubuntu.com/a/1335263/124466

Comment: Yes, if you increase RAM to 4 GB then Ubuntu would run quite smoothly. But check out the alternative flavors (in the link I posted), which all consume less RAM than Ubuntu.

Comment: I test Lubuntu & other *flavors* using devices with as little as 2GB of RAM...   I still use 1GB devices on occasion, so yes you can run software, but you need to work *differently* (ie. consider your resources & what applications you use, esp. at the same time) to boxes that have more RAM.  I'd suggest a lighter flavor, but note 20.04 won't be the latest; 20.04 = 2020-April which was 3 releases ago!  Your answer depends on what you want to, and details you've not provided.  Yes it may run, may well run, may run slow, other choices maybe better - depends on how you'll use it.

Comment: According to [ark.intel.com](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/78429/intel-pentium-processor-a1018-1m-cache-2-10-ghz.html) this CPU supports upto 32Gb of RAM. So you can really install additional 8 Gb stick to have 10 Gb of RAM. For sure check your laptop model and its support page. GNOME Shell is to heavy for this CPU, so you can install any Ubuntu variant like Lubuntu, MATE or Xfce.

Comment: @N0rbert The answers of that question are outdated. No information about 20.04 or 21.04

Comment: What differences has 20.04 & 21.04 have @ArchismanPanigrahi, the last *major* minimum specification change was made for 17.10 or the re-introduction of GNOME on Ubuntu Desktop (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).  Some desktops/flavors no longer provide minimums (eg. Lubuntu hasn't since the 18.04/LXDE days; Xubuntu likewise doesn't... etc) but no change was made since 2019 (*excluding of removal of no-longer supported details*)

Comment: Thank you, @Archisman Panigrahi, guiverc, N0rbert, karel